# Unexpected C++ queue behavior, losing the object after I pop

Tags: c++

`queue<vector<int>>` does not behave as expected. I seem to lose access to the reference to the `vector` after the `pop()`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct TreeNode {
    string val;
    TreeNode(string x) : val(x) {}
};

int main() {

    queue<int> q = {};


    q.push(1);
    q.push(2);

    int& test = q.front();
    q.pop();
    // queue<int>; front() and then pop() behaves as expected
    cout << "test1 " << test  << " expect: 1" << endl;

    TreeNode n1("node a");
    TreeNode n2("node b");
    queue<TreeNode> q2 = {};


    q2.push(n1);
    q2.push(n2);

    TreeNode& test2 = q2.front();
    q2.pop();

    // queue<TreeNode>; front() and then pop() behaves as expected    
    cout << "test2 " << test2.val  << " expect: node b" << endl;


    vector<int> v1 = {0,1,2};
    vector<int> v2 = {2,3,4};

    queue<vector<int>> q3 = {};

    q3.push(v1);
    q3.push(v2);
    vector<int>& test3 = q3.front();
    // front() alone returns what I expected
    cout << "test3 size " << test3.size() << " expect: size 3" << endl;

    vector<int>& test4 = q3.front();
    q3.pop();
    // however front() and then pop() does not behave as expected    
    cout << "test4 size " << test3.size() << " expect: size 4" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
test1 1 expect: 1
test2 node a expect: node b
test3 size 3 expect: size 3
test4 size 0 expect: size 4

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Questions:

Is there any code smell with the above examples? Should I always expect to lose the reference after the `pop()`? Should I never use the reference after the `pop()`?

Or is `vector` a special case?

`EDIT: knowing that dangling reference is always bad practice. I made some changes to the code and now have some follow up questions.`

Follow up question:

```
queue<int> q = {};
q.push(1);
q.push(2);
// making a copy here
// follow up question 1: is this now correct?
int test = q.front();
q.pop();


vector<int> v1 = {0,1,2};
vector<int> v2 = {2,3,4};

queue<vector<int>> q3 = {};

q3.push(v1);
q3.push(v2);

// I am trying to make a copy here but the compiler complains:
// Parameter type mismatch: expression must be rvalue
// follow up question 2: why can't I make a copy of the vector but I can make a copy of the int in the previous example?
vector<int> test3 = q3.front();
q3.pop()
```

Comment: Of course you're losing the reference. After you `pop()`, the reference to the former element at the beginning of the queue is now a dangling reference into never-never land, and using it is textbook undefined behavior. What exactly are you unclear about?

Comment: You should post a new question for new questions, rather than continually extending the same question. If you do, post a MCVE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are storing a reference to an object and then destroying the object. Once you `pop` it off the queue, it's no longer on the queue. Either make a copy of the object or don't `pop` it until you're done with it.

Again, never ever try to access an object that no longer exists. The results will be unpredictable.

Comment: So that means even queue<int> example is wrong? It is just that it undefined behavior, so I somehow still manage to find the int that I was looking for in `test1`?

Comment: You cannot possibly have found the int you were looking for in `test1` since that `int` no longer exists. You might have happened to see the value that you happened to expect. But that's as much an accident of your expectations as of what happened. (Why would you expect the value to stay the same?)

Comment: @samol: yes, even the `queue<int>` example is wrong. A dangling reference is always wrong, regardless of what it is referencing

Comment: I am realizing how dumb my questions have been. Thank you for being patient with me. I added 2 follow up questions. Could you help answer the follow up questions?

Comment: The answer to your first followup question is yes. The answer to your second followup question is that you are probably doing something silly as that code should compile and compiles/runs fine for me.